# Django admin/ Chart js error - super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

Tags: python, django, chart.js

I am overriding django admin (using changelist_view) to display a bar chart (using chart.js) above the data in an admin view. Using this example as a reference: https://findwork.dev/blog/adding-charts-to-django-admin/ .

Getting Error:

```
TypeError at /admin/machines/machinescurrentdaythreadbreaks/
super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost/admin/machines/machinescurrentdaythreadbreaks/
Django Version: 1.9
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
Exception Location: /home/epicar/EPIC-Django/EPIC_AR/machines/admin.py in changelist_view, line 557
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.9
Python Path:    
['/home/epicar/EPIC-Django/EPIC_AR',
'/home/epicar/EPIC-Django/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
'/usr/lib/python2.7',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
'/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2']
Server time:    Thu, 9 Jan 2020 17:50:04 +0000
```

admin.py looks like this for model:

```
def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
    # Aggregate breaks per head, per needle
    chart_data = (
        MachinesCurrentDayThreadBreaks.objects.annotate(breaks=Count("sum"))
        .values("sum")
        .annotate(y=Count("sum"))
        .order_by("head_position")
    )

    # Serialize and attach the chart data to the template context
    as_json = json.dumps(list(chart_data), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
    extra_context = extra_context or {"chart_data": as_json}

    # Call the superclass changelist_view to render the page
    return super().changelist_view(request, extra_context=extra_context)
```

Comment: Either upgrade the python you are using or change the call to `super(admin.ModelAdmin,self)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you use `Python Version: 2.7.9` and author of your artical use `Python 3.7.3`

You can try use this for fix

```
return super(admin.ModelAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context=extra_context)
```

But i gues this is not the only place where you'll get errors

Comment: Added the argument to super and I at least got a different result. But if I do the tutorial as is - I don't get any errors. The chart displays just fine. It's when I got to alter the admin to connect to the live data it starts throwing errors (or shutting down the server.